# OpenGL using std::vector with glm::vec3

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, glm-math

I'm having the following issue.

I've loaded 8 glm::vec3 into a std::vector, such that:

```
std::vector <glm::vec3> vertices;
```

returns:

**0.250000 -0.250000 -0.250000

0.250000 -0.250000 0.250000

-0.250000 -0.250000 0.250000

-0.250000 -0.250000 -0.250000

0.250000 0.250000 -0.250000

0.250000 0.250000 0.250000

-0.250000 0.250000 0.250000

-0.250000 0.250000 -0.250000**

if:

```
for(int i{0}; i<8; i++){
    std::cout<<"\n";
    for(int j{0}; j<3; j++){
    std::cout<<vertices[i][j]<<" ";
    }
}
```

When I pass the following code into OpenGL,

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size(), &vertices[0],  GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);  

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 

glBindVertexArray(buffer);
```

my shader program loads and the window opens, however there is no cube.

A slight alteration to the first line,

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vert), &vert, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW); //Here

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindVertexArray(buffer);
```

while taking vectors from,

```
const GLfloat vert[9] =
{-0.5,-0.5, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
  0.5,-0.5, 0.0};
```

and a pretty red triangle is drawn onto the screen.

**My question:** *Is it possible to use a vector container in combination with glm? If so, how can it be implemented?*
**My hypothesis:***The glVertexAttribPointer function is reading sequentially from the starting address of the vertices container. The elements of the vertices container are fragmented throughout my memory.*

Comment: It is possible to interoperate glm types with OpenGL's types, my guess is that something else is wrong with the cube or how you're drawing it. Since the triangle verts you mention with the float array works, you could try using a glm::vec3 array there instead and see what happens.

Comment: Is `buffer` the vertex array object you have bound during the draw calls?

Comment: @Twinklebear the way I was drawing it only rendered properly for two dimensional objects. I fixed that in 2 seconds, choosing instead to use`glDrawElements` and the faces in my cube.obj file to connect the dots.

Comment: Then why do you have a VAO if you're not using it for drawing? It's really hard to tell what is going on without more code, but the code fragments shown here suggest that you're using the VAO incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe, I'm not quite understanding the way this all works. I created a VAO in main `GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);`  <br/> what I have bound in 'glBindVertexArray(buffer);` is the VBO, which I thought was saved onto the VAO because of the `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);` and 
`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vert), &vert, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);` **GL_ARRAY_BUFFER** parameter target. Is this not the way this works? If not, then why is it drawing the object I want it to? I still have not worked out the shaders. All I see is a red square.

Comment: But I'm assuming that the red square is really a cube. All I have to do is work out the shaders and rotate the camera. Am I far off? I'd love to show you my code, but I'm afraid it would be too chaotic for anyone to grasp.

Comment: I see no reason for that line to break. Why don't you take the working example with the triangle and only replace the array with a `std::vector<glm::vec3>`?

Answer (score 2):

In your `glBufferData()` `&vertices[0]` should probably have been, `&vertices[0].x`.
That's because `&vertices[0]` points to a `glm::vec3` but you want it to point to a `float`
because that's what OpenGL expects.

Comment: It does point to a glm::vec3. I tried your method and I've also tried `&vertices[0][0]`. Still, it does not render.

Comment: @a_learner is it possible that `vertices` gets destructed after calling `glBufferData`?

Comment: No, `vertices` is a `public:` vector container from an object that I'm calling from `main()`. I checked the `vertices` with a `for` loop from main, after calling `glBufferData`from a function that is public under the same class as `vertices`.

Comment: @a_learner what are the values of `std::vector<float> vv(&vertices[0].x, &vertices[0].x + sizeof(vertex) * vertices.size());`?

Comment: I see what you did there. `std::vector<GLfloat> vv(&vertices[0].x, &vertices[0].x + sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size());` gave me an exact copy of `vertices`. I then made a copy `std::vector <GLfloat> v` under the `public` of that class so it wouldn't be destroyed once I left the function call. I `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3)*vertices.size(), &v, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);` **AND BAM IT DREW SOMETHING!** It's not exactly a cube, but damn it's something!

Comment: Cube accomplished. This was my first time loading vertex data from a .obj file. I know your code worked, I'm going to study the details tomorrow, but likely I'm going change my approach since copying the container is going to kill performance. I may just throw it all into a `std::vector <GLfloat>` and forget 'std::vector <glm::vec3>` altogether. I might also forget about `std::vector` and store it some other way. I've heard of performance issues with `std::vector` for things greater than a cube.

Comment: @a_learner yes, using an array of floats is usually the way it's done. `std::vector`s are fine though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are allowed to pass complex types to the shader. I have always created a struct with a float array for the positions:

```
struct vertex{
    GLfloat positions[3];
};
```

Then to use in your code:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex) * vertices.size(),
             &vertices[0],  GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);  

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 

glBindVertexArray(buffer);
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative, but surely OpenGL would allow you to send a glm::vec3 to the shader. First of all, they are essentially small arrays of floats, and secondly, GLM is the OpenGL math library, so why would they design it not to be compatible with their shaders?

Comment: This method allows for all the data for each vertex to be packaged nicely, ie. texture coordinates and normal vectors.

Comment: Yes, I know your way is one of the more popular methods.

Comment: You are allowed to pass complex types, as long as they are designed to do so. And GLM library was designed just to support this type of usage. So there is really no point in re-inventing the wheel with own classes for vectors and matrices. And GLM is NOT part of OpenGL nor it comes from any corner of Khronos group. It is external tool based on the GLSL specs. There could be bugs or some undefined behaviour, but it's here for years and proved to be really stable and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have back face culling enabled? Because if you have no view matrix set up or your camera is inside the cube, then you probably see only the back faces, which may be culled, whereas in your second example the triangle faces you with its front face, thus being visible.

Answer (score 0):

[C++11's `std::vector` has a built-in function `data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), which returns a pointer to the underlying data, such that [`data()`, `data() + size()`] is a valid range for the vector.

Furthermore, you don't need to ask for any data pointers when working with arrays of glm::ivec types. The following code example is perfectly valid OpenGL code and will render without trouble:

```
glm::vec3 vertices[] = {
    glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec3(0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec3(1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f)
};
int sizeVertices = sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(glm::vec3);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// ...
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, sizeVertices);
```